# Why can't I do assignment outside a method?

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

If I try to assign a value to a variable in a class, but outside a method I get an error.

```
class one{
 Integer b;
 b=Integer.valueOf(2);
}
```

but, if I initialize it during the creation, it works.

```
class one{
 Integer b=Integer.valueOf(2);
}
```

Inside a method, it works in both cases.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you need to do

```
class one{
 Integer b;
 {
    b=Integer.valueOf(2);
 }
}
```

as statements have to appear in a block of code.

In this case, the block is an initailiser block which is added to every constructor (or the default constructor in this case) It is run after any call to `super()` and before the main block of code in any constructor.

BTW: You can have a static initialiser block with `static { }` which is called when the class is initialised.

e.g.

```
class one{
 static final Integer b;

 static {
    b=Integer.valueOf(2);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Because the **assignments** are **statements** and **statements** are allowed **only inside** blocks of code(methods, constructors, static initializers, etc.)

Outside of these only declarations are allowed.

This :

```
  class one{
        Integer b=Integer.valueOf(2);
  }
```

is a declaration with an initializer. That's why is accepted

Comment: Why statements are allowed only inside blocks of code ?

Comment: The assertion above is that "only declarations are allowed", however the example code includes Declaration, Instantiation and Initialization. I'd let it pass if there was a comma instead of a period after that sentence...

Comment: @JasonK. The example code includes a field declaration, and the field declaration *has* an initialiser, which is an expression. The class body still only contains declarations. (Note that the accepted answer doesn't contradict this - the class initialiser is also a declaration.)

Answer (score 3):

A more general answer would be that the class body is about *declarations*, not statements. There is a special provision for statements occuring in class body, but they have to be marked explicitly as either class initializers or instance initializers.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, when defining a class, you can define variables with default values and add methods. Any executable code (such as assignments) MUST be contained in a method.

Comment: You're a method, I'm a function.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way java works, you cannot add non-declaration code (sorry i don't know the correct term) inside the class, that code should be inside methods.

Comment: did you test the code in the question, did you even read the question...

Answer (score 0):

I think terminology-wise, couple of other answers are slightly off. Declarations are also statements. In fact, they are called "declaration statements", which are one of the three kinds of statements. An assignment statement is one form of "expression statement" and can be used only in constructs such as methods, constructors, and initializers. Check out the Statements section in this [Oracle's tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Methods have the responsibility to perform mutations on the member variables.  If the member variable needs to be initialized, java provides a way to do it during construction, class definition (latter case). But the mutation cannot be performed during definition.(former case).  It is usually done at the method level.

Objects are meant to hold the state, while methods are meant to operate on that state.