# Syntax error on tokens

Tags: java, dictionary, syntax, hashmap, syntax-error

I am getting an error which i don't understand:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

The following is my code for the class, error occurs in line 8 (marked):

```
import java.util.*;

public class stringCalculator {
    String operator_array[] = {"+", "-", "/", "*", "(", ")"};
    Queue<Integer> outputQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Stack <Object> operatorStack = new Stack<Object>();
    Hashtable<String, Integer> precendece = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    precedence.put("+", 2); <=========== This is where the error occurs

    public void printTokenList(String [] expression, int length)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            System.out.println(expression[i]);
        }
    }

    public void checkInput(String [] expression, int length)
    {
        System.out.println(expression);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
                if(checkIfNumber(expression[i])){
                int new_expression = Integer.parseInt(expression[i]);
                outputQueue.add(new_expression);
            }
            else if(expression[i].equals("+") || expression[i].equals("-") || expression[i].equals("/") || expression[i].equals("*")){
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                    if(expression[i].equals(operator_array[j])){
                    operatorStack.push(expression[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkIfNumber(String expression)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
          double number = Double.parseDouble(expression);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;
      }  
      return true;  
    }

    public void checkPrecedence()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize the Hashtable in constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `precedence.put("+", 2);` has to be within a method or a block.

For example, you can place it within the constructor

```
public stringCalculator() {
    precedence.put("+", 2);
}
```

Not related to the problem you have, classes need to start with a capital letter, according to the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 0):

Statements should be placed in inside constructors/methods/blocks, otherwise Compile time error occurs.

```
precedence.put("+", 2); <=========== This is where the error occurs
```

Move that line to constructor/method.

Answer (score 0):

```
precedence.put("+", 2); <=========== This is where the error occurs
```

this statement is not inside any block , hence it is not permitted.

remove it from here and put it inside any other method or block

Note: this is how java works.

for an extended discussion, please refer to:

[Why can't I do assignment outside a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/java-why-outisde-a-method-i-cant-do-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
precedence.put("+", 2);
```

The above line is incorrectly placed. You should initialise the Hashtable in constructor.