# Initialisation of variable in java

Tags: java, variables

In my program i tried to initialize a variable after declaring it, but i can't. Please Explain why i can't initialize after declaring.

```
class Animal
{
    int var;
    var=99; //Getting errors when i try to initialize here
    void Print()
    {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}

class Dog
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Animal obj=new Animal();
        obj.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try in one line, int var = 99;

Comment: You need to make variable assignments on one line (when they aren't part of a method). Also remove the `+` from `System.out.println(+var);`

Comment: Duplicate question . Look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/why-cant-i-do-assignment-outside-a-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours statement is invalid.

You can do a declaration statement or flow statement.

What you are doing is a flow statement which you can do while declaration, inside constructors or methods and static and non-static blocks.

> expression statements, there are two other kinds of statements: declaration statements and control flow statements. A declaration statement declares a variable. You've seen many examples of declaration statements already:

```
// declaration statement
double aValue = 8933.234;
```

> Finally, control flow statements regulate the order in which statements get executed.

Read about [`statements and Expressions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)