# why cant i use System.out.println out side a method and when i try to use the method of my main class in other class it shows identifier not found

Tags: java, arrays, methods

why cant i use System.out.println out side a method and when i try to use the method of my main class in other class it shows identifier not found 
may be there are better way to do this . but i would like to learn this what is wrong here

```
package arraytest;           //package declared 
import java.util.Scanner;    // for input

public class Arr {           // this is my main class 

    void min(int arr[])
    {
      int min=arr[0];  

      for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)  
       { if(min>arr[i])  
         min=arr[i];  
       }
   System.out.println(min);  

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

       Array a=new Array();
       a.inputData();
       a.display();
       a.min();
    }
}



class Array
 {

        int arr[]=new int[5];
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
       // System.out.println(arr.length);   will not work why?

        void inputData()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
             {
               arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
             }

        }

         void display()
        {
             for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
             {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
             }

        }

     void min()
    {         
     Arr a=new Arr();    
     a.min(int arr[]);  // this shows error
     } 

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in your `min()` method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/why-cant-i-do-assignment-outside-a-method

Comment: to find the minimum value in the array

Comment: Imperative code statements have to be placed in a method.  You can't just put lines of code randomly throughout your classes.

Comment: okay thanks i got the answer for my first question . but the second part is still not clear to me

Comment: @deepakpandey: In the `min()` method at the very end of your code there appears to be a syntax error.  You're trying to declare a variable *inside of a method call*.  You can't do that.  Declare variables on their own line, then call the method with that variable.

Comment: @david are u saying about  a.min(int arr[]);  this arr[] is array and i have declared it already . although i found it should be a.min(arr)

Comment: @deepakpandey: According to the comment in your code, that is the line showing an error.  The error is as I explained.

Comment: @ david why cant i pass array to the method to main class from other class

Comment: thanks david i got your point syntax error to add "int" there

Answer (score 1):

You can't put code there.  Your code has to be inside of a method.  The 2 lines above that are declarations, and the `System.out.println` is code.

Code has to go inside a method.'

You could use a static block if your `arr` was static, but it's not.

Comment: okay thanks i got the answer for my first question . but the second part is still not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Change you min method as below,

```
void min() {
    Arr a = new Arr();
    a.min(arr);  // this shows error
}
```

This is how you pass a reference of an array to the method.