# How do I properly add a private class within a public class in the Eclipse Neon editor?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to make a Java program where it asks the user for the diameter and height of a cylinder, where it only takes the input as a positive integer less than 2,147,483,648, and then calculates a volume and surface area from that input. My problem is trying to validate the user input, running an error message ("Please enter an integer value (less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal: ")
if the user enters a word or invalid number, and then allows the user to put in a new valid answer.

I tried making a private class to check if the user input was valid *after* the programs asks for the user input, using the same defined integers (diameter; height isn't done yet...). This is also before the mathematical calculations are performed to find the volume and surface area. **My problem** is that my brackets are being shown as errors by the Eclipse editor when I try closing the public class after the volume/SA formulas. Sorry for the long code. Thank you in advance for any help, very much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ContainerCalculator 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int height = 0;
            int diameter = 0;
            double surfaceArea = 0.0;
            double volume = 0.0;
            double radius = 0.0; 
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Container Calculator!");
            System.out.println("====================================");

             //User prompts to get the diameter and height of the cylinder.

            System.out.println("Enter the diameter of a cylinder (in centimeters): ");
            diameter = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Enter the height of a cylinder (in centimeters): ");
            height = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");

        }


        private static int inputChecker(Scanner scnr) {
            int i = 0;
            int diameter = -1;
            int height = -1;
            while (i==0){
                while (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter an integer value (less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal: ");
                    scnr.nextLine();
                }

                while (scnr.hasNextInt()){
                    diameter = scnr.nextInt();
                    // check to see if it is negative or past a 32-bit range (within range)
                    if ((diameter >= 0) && (diameter < 2147483647)) {
                        i++;
                        return diameter;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer value (less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
                        scnr.nextLine();
                    }
                }

            }
            return -1;
        }




    //VOLUME CALCULATIONS:
        radius = diameter / 2.0; 
        volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,  2.0) * height;

        System.out.println("A can with a diameter of " + diameter + 
                " and a height of " + height + " has ");
        System.out.print("\ta volume of ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", volume);
        System.out.println(","); 

        //SURFACE AREA CALCULATIONS: 
        surfaceArea = (2.0 * Math.PI * radius * height) + (2.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0));

        System.out.print("\tand a surface area of ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", surfaceArea);
        System.out.print(".");
        System.out.println("");


        System.out.println("=============================================");
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Container Calculator."); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I do assignment outside a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/why-cant-i-do-assignment-outside-a-method)

Comment: All your code must be in methods, the code starting with `//VOLUME CALCULATIONS:` is not in a method.

Answer (score 1):

Reading user input:

```
while (true) {

// read line, e.g. String line = reader.readline();
// try to parse line as int, e.g. Integer.valueOf(line); if this does not throw an exception, break;
// catch NumberformatException, print error, next try

}
```