# Cannot create WifiConfiguration

Tags: java, android, wifi

I am trying to create a WifiConfiguration, however, if I write the following:

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
```

The ide gives this error:

```
unknown class: conf.SSID
```

I also tried the following code:

```
WifiConfiguration conf ;
conf = new WifiConfiguration();
```

However, it now gives the error:

```
Invalid method declaration
```

What could be wrong? I do have the

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
```

at the beginning of my file

[Here is an image of the actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R843.png)

Comment: post the complete code where you are using `conf = new WifiConfiguration();`

Comment: Hi, I have attached an image at the end of the post
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R843.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have a [statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) in a class body ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/why-cant-i-do-assignment-outside-a-method)). You need to move `conf.SSID` to your `onCreate()` method. Also please go through  [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
conf.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
```