# ArrayList doesn't work

Tags: java, android, arraylist

[image: printscreen]

Arraylist won't work.

edit: thanks for the helpers! question been answered.

Comment: you need some Primary knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I do assignment outside a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/why-cant-i-do-assignment-outside-a-method)

Comment: Please try to post code the next time. Images do not serve a great purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is simply outside of any method curly braces. You need to write this code in the `onCreate()` method or any other method of your own and call it.

Comment: Thank you so much! can't believe i missed it

Comment: No worries, glad it helped! Cheers! You can mark the question as answered if this solved your problem ;)