# Error on a Java timer

Tags: java

I have this code in my Java class

```
package me.mario.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

public class AutoSyncDatabase {
    Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    };
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

But I get the error `Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens` on this line:

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I tried a lot of ways to fix it but without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: call `scheduleAtFixedRate` in a method

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12062536/1531124 from the duplicated question. Statements need to go into some sort of **block**. Like a block, or a method.

Comment: Beyond that: when you are really struggling with such basic syntax things, are you sure that advanced concurrency code is fitting your current skill level?